# Finding the average of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, average, pattern-recognition

Given the sequence $5,-10,15,-20,25,-30,...$ find the average of the first 200 terms.

Is the formula that I am supposed to use is $t_n=a+(n-1)d$ ?

I know that $a = 5$, but I'm confused about the common difference and how to find the average of $200$ terms.

Comment: I don't see how the average can be $-5$, since it appears the sum is $-500$ and thus the average would be $\frac{-500}{200}=\frac{-5}{2}$.

Comment: The $a$ is not the average, but the $a$ from the "sequence law".

Comment: a meaning first term, the OP is stating the obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice:

There are 2 AP's here

$$5,15,25..$$

$$-10, -20, -30 ..$$

In the first, $a= 5$, $d =  10$

In the second $a = -10$, $d= -10$

Since $S_n=(\frac{n}{2})(2a+(n-1)d)$

so $(\frac{100}{2})(2\times5 + (99)10 + 2\times-10 + (99)-10)$ and divide the entire thing by 200

Comment: How did you find 99? Or is that the value you should always sub in when finding the average of 2 AP'S?

Comment: There are 100 terms of each sequence. Plug it into the formula n-1

Comment: After calculating the results using BEDMAS/PEMDAS and dividing the entire thing by 200, I got 5.37 as my answer. Is that correct?

Comment: Show me ur working

Comment: It's incorrect.

Comment: What was my mistake?

Comment: As I said, show me how you did it..

Comment: You shoukd be getting -0.025

Comment: Let me know if it helped.

Comment: 1)  5+99*10+-10+(99)-10  2.) 5+990-10+99-10 = 1074  3.) 995-10+99-10  4.) 985 + 99 -10 = 1074/200 = 5.37

Comment: I think I know what you did there. I'll try again.

Comment: (5 + (99*10)) +( -10 + (99*-10)) and divide the entire thing by 200

Comment: 995-1000/200 = -5/200 = -0.025

Comment: How to do that? I just joined this site today, lol. :B

Comment: Done and done...

Comment: @TripleA, You have taken $t_n$($n^{th}$ term of AP) instead of $S_n$(Sum of $n$ terms). The answer should have been $-\frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: I just plugged it into his formula

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

Take $5,15,25,\dots$ and $-10,-20,-30,\dots$ as two different arithmetic series.  Then average the first $100$ terms of each.

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$5, -10, 15, -20, 25, -30, ... $$
taking two terms at a time we have,
$$-5, -5, -5,...$$
So sum of n terms can be given as:
$$S_{\ n\ (is\ even)} = -(\frac{n}{2})5$$
$$S_{\ n\ (is\ odd)} = S_{n-1}+T_n = -(\frac{n-1}{2})5+5+(\frac{n-1}{2})10$$$$=(\frac{n+1}{2})5$$
Note: $T_n$ of sequence$(5,-10,15,...)=t_{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ of sequence$(5,15,25,...)$ when n is odd.